# Headers inception - Forward Declaration

Tags: c, forward-declaration

So, I have something like this:

main.c, enemy.c, player.c, technique.c, dialog.c
and their headers:
main.h, enemy.h, player.h, technique.h, dialog.h

Everything was working fine, I was using all of them except from enemy.c (this file had no functions).
I decided to start the code for enemy's attack.

```
    void eAttack(player *p, enemy *e)
    {
    code;
    }
```

But I'm getting an error like this:

```
    In file included from main.c:1:
    In file included from ./include/main.h:8:
    In file included from ./include/player.h:8
    ./include/enemy.h:18:14: error: unknown type name 'player'
    void eAttack(player *p, enemy *e);
```

thing is, I have the same function at player.c, pAttack(player *p, enemy *e);
and it was working fine until I started coding enemy.c.
I read about it and I think the problem is forward declaration and 'guards' because if I erase the #include "player.h" from enemy it says the same for player.c, and if I erase both still doesn't work. 
I only found c++ answers, still don't know how to fix this using C.

Comment: If functions in enemy.h rely on types from player.h, you should either #include player.h in enemy.h, or forward-declare the types in enemy.h.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `player` type must be known by `enemy.c` and `enemy` type must be knowm by `player.c` right?

You must include your header(s) after those types declaration in order to avoid `unknown type`s:

/* main.c */

```
#include "player.h"
#include "enemy.h"

int main(void)
{
    player p = {1};
    enemy e = {2};

    pAttack(&p, &e);
    eAttack(&p, &e);
    return 0;
}
```

/* player.h */

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

typedef struct {
    int bla;
} player;

#include "enemy.h"

void pAttack(player *p, enemy *e);

#endif
```

/* enemy.h */

```
#ifndef ENEMY_H
#define ENEMY_H

typedef struct {
    int bla;
} enemy;

#include "player.h"

void eAttack(player *p, enemy *e);

#endif
```

/* player.c */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "player.h"

void pAttack(player *p, enemy *e)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", p->bla, e->bla);
}
```

/* enemy.c */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "enemy.h"

void eAttack(player *p, enemy *e)
{
    printf("%d %d\n", p->bla, e->bla);
}
```